# User-created routes ExpressJS

Tags: html, express

there are websites which create custom sessions for users, giving them unique link to the exact session user has created. E.g. it would like something like https/website.com/session/UniqueRandomID. I guess I understand how custom routes in ExpressJS work, but I'm not quite sure how can I allow a user to create those and later allow other users to connect only to those which have been already created..

Is there a common way of doing it and what may I be missing on the topic?

I tried searching the expressJS documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "session" has a rather specific meaning in web site development (it refers to data associated with a given browser's visit to a site and is used for things like tracking the logged in state of a user) so I'll use the term "project" in this answer.

When the user creates a project, store all the information about that project in a database. Include, as part of this information an identifier. You probably want this to be a GUID or similar (there are libraries which will generates these for you) rather than something sequential (like an automatically generated database primary key).

The first page of the React Guide explains [routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Create a route that uses a *route parameter* for the project ID.

Use that project ID to get the data about the project from your database.

If there isn't any for that ID, return an error.

```
app.get('/projects/:projectId', async (req, res) => {
    const projectData = await getProjectData(req.params.projectId);
    if (projectData) {
        return res.render('projectView', projectData);
    }
    res.sendStatus(404);

})
```

Comment: Is there a way of creating the "project" without the database? The created route should exist only while used so it is not essential to store it. Can I somehow manage it on the server only?

Comment: I'm using the term "database" very loosely here. It is a place where you store and organise your data. That can be a plain, in-memory, JS object. (A RDBMS or no-sql database is probably still *better* as it gives you a lot more robustness).

Comment: It is still a little bit unclear to me how should I create such route...

Comment: I literally gave you all of the code related to creating the route in the answer. You just need to take care of writing the code to store and fetch the data you want to use in it.